# Chrome having issues drawing large tables when scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web

I have created my own grid (table) using jQuery and when there are a lot of rows Chrome seems to have issues with drawing the table background and text colours properly. When scrolling up and down the page any previously coloured rows will become uncoloured when you scroll back to their position on the page.

Has anyone else experienced this before and if so what can I do to solve this?

Comment: More details please. How many rows are we talking? Did you test in any other browser?

Comment: It usually begins to happen with over 200 rows. Same issue seems to appear across all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with chrome, some rows didn't colour but others did.. was really random.

What I found is that if you have a background colour and text colour assigned to your tr tag, (as well as a background colour / text colour assigned to the td tag), sometimes the browsers gets a little confused when rendering large table structures..

My advice, only style your td tags not your tr tags if you want unique styling.

Hope it helps